# Neo4j query to bring back user interests and interests connected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two Neo4j nodes, users and interests. Users are related to interests and interests can be connected to other interests.

I want to write a Cypher query that retrieves interests for a user but also tells me which interests are connected. If the interests are connected to other interests which the user is not interested in, they should not be returned.

So for example, Bob is interested in Finance and Bitcoin and Finance and Bitcoin are connected. Bitcoin is also connected to Blockchain but the user is not interested in this so this relationship should not be returned.

Here is what I have so far:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:INTERESTED_IN]-(i:Interest) 
WHERE u.name = 'Bob' 
RETURN u, r, i
```

This brings back the individual interests but is there a simple way to bring back connected interests in the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

`MATCH 
   (u:User)-[r1:INTERESTED_IN]-(i1:Interest),
   (u)-[r2:INTERESTED_IN]-(i2:Interest),
   (i1)-[:RELATED]-(i2)
WHERE u.name = 'Bob' 
RETURN u, r1, i1, r2, i2`

Here I've assumed that interests are related via `:RELATED`, adjust as necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much. This works for a user that where the interests are related but if the interests are not related, there are no results. Can the query be updated to handle both situations?

Comment: Yes -- on the `(i1)-[:RELATED]-(i2)` use OPTIONAL MATCH